# Smart Target kettle job is not running

Tags: fredhopper, web8.5

I have created a promotion in Smart Target and published it and I can see promotion file is deployed in fredhopper indexer instance . But it is not getting processed by STkettle job immediately. If I run manually it is getting processed.

Here is my few question,

1.How can I know what is schedule interval and whether ST kettle job is running or not.
2. Does ST kettle job start to run automatically when we start fredhopper instance through command prompt.

3.will I be able to see the promotion immediately in preview mode of indexer server and query server?

Please note that i am using below fredhopper version

Fredhopper version: fredhopper-7.5.2.10 
SDL Web : SDL Web 8.5

Comment: Can you add version information? SDL Web/Tridion version, Fredhopper version. Thanks.

Comment: Fredhopper version:  fredhopper-7.5.2.10 and SDL Web : SDL Web 8.5

Answer (score 2):

Deployer is responsible for calling the STJob and if it is not happening with your environment,

1. Please make sure you have configured the  Tag correctly  under the in the SmartTarget configuration file of the deployer configuration
2. when you publish it will start automatically, no need to schedule it in intervals
3. Yes, you would be able to see the promotion immediately in indexer after publish is succesful, might take a bit for the query server based on settings
4. Make sure you have also given sufficient permissions for the deployer to run the kettle job, more details can be found about your issue with kettle when you turn the deployer log level to debug